# Have built x Will have built

Tags: word-in-context

In The Beatles song "O-bla-di O-bla-da" Paul Mccartney sings:

> In a couple of years they have built a home sweet home

As far as I can understand he is singing about something that will occur in the future, so shouldn't he sing "In a couple of years they will have built a home sweet home" instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nonstandard usage is fairly common in lyrics (or poetry), either to make the words fit a meter or rhyming scheme, or for some specific poetic effect.

In this case, here's what I think is going on. The whole song is in the present tense (e.g. "Molly stays at home and does her pretty face"). In the line you identified, the writer wants to indicate that two years have passed in the narrative, but it "jumps" to this point in the future so that everything is still present tense. I think it would be more grammatical to say "after a couple of years they have built a home sweet home" but "after" has more syllables than "in" so it wouldn't fit as well.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I think this is a big problem for non-native English speakers - you never know how far you can go with this kind of 'breaking the rules' with grammar before you start sounding completely ridiculous :)